# Can Quabr Scraping be Prevented?

Tags: support, scraping

I noticed Quabr.com had scraped [one of my questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27069548/2642059): http://quabr.com/27069548/is-tr2-going-to-be-released-in-c17

Does StackOverflow do anything to defend against scraping? Can anything be done to force Quabr to take down that content?

Comment: They have a notice on the bottom about being a proxy (mirror?) for Stack Overflow, and attribution is being given. I don't see anything wrong here after a quick glance.

Comment: @KevinBrown I did see that, I just hate the idea of scrapers on the site period and even worse the idea of them making money off Stack Overflow.

Comment: In short - when you post content to SO you do so under the T&C's of the site that you agree to publish said content using a CC-BY-SA 3.0. As long as the content is correctly attributed - it's fine. That site clearly says "imported from Stackoverflow" and retains a link to the original SO post. There's nothing to "prevent" here...

Comment: They do seem to have omitted the links to the posters' SO profiles, which is one of the attribution requirements.

Comment: In theory, individual users could attack scraping sites  that violate the CC license of their own content (like, file a DMCA takedown request)  even when Stack Overflow chooses not to do anything against that specific scraper. But as Jon says, if the terms of the license are obeyed, scraping is fair game. It's a small downside of the very liberal license under which content is posted here.